# Pandas: Creating an index year ago for multiple items

Tags: pandas, date, pandas-groupby

I can create an index vs the previous year when I have just one item, but I'm trying to figure out how to do this when I have multiple items. 
 Here is my data set: 
[image]

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=3, freq='Y')
rng = np.repeat(rng,3)
country = ["USA","Brazil","Japan"]*3
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':country,'date':rng,'value':range(20,29)})
```

If I only had one item/country I can do something like this:

```
df['pct_iya'] = 100*(df['value'].pct_change()+1)
```

I'm trying to get this to work with multiple items.  Here is the expected result:
[image]

Maybe this could work with a groupby, but my attempt did not work...

```
df['pct_iya2'] = df.groupby(['Country','date'])['value'].pct_change()
```

Comment: Try removing `'date'` from your `groupby`. When you group by both, there is only one observation for the combination `Brazil` - `12/31/2011` and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Use a group by (excluding date) and than add one to the percent change (ex +15percent goes from .15 to 1.15), then multiple you 100.

```
df['pct_iya'] = 100*(df.groupby(['Country'])['value'].pct_change()+1)
```